# Freeway sign and bridge detection

Tags: c, image-processing, ubuntu, opencv

I am working on a project in scene Identification in OpenCV on Ubuntu. I need to detect freeway signs and bridges in it. I have converted the image to HSV, and after thresholding and dilation I get a rectangle which is disconnected, which is why the contour mapping cannot detect it as a rectangle. Can someone please suggest a method to either extrapolate the lines to complete a rectangle or some other way to detect a freeway sign? I also need ideas to for an overpass or bridge detection.

Comment: Why do you want to detect bridges and freeway signs, just curious.

Comment: Well I want to detect and display these as some of the features to help classify the scene

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the MUTCD standards for color of the sign to extract it ?
http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/kno-colorspec.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [paper](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=freeway%20sign%20detection%20in%20opencv&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://crit2007.bartlab.org/Dr.%2520Jackrit%2527s%2520Papers/ney/1.TRAFFIC_SIGN_Lorsakul_ISR.pdf&ei=rxEXT7GBF6SaiQf01OzxAw&usg=AFQjCNFiJ6TvqUx4vDDksTMrOfHFmCn0JQ&cad=rja). It uses edge detection.

Otherwise, use contour to detect blob from thresholded image ( even if detected blob is not rectangle ), and use the function [boundingRect](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-boundingrect) to get minimal rectangle holding blob which, i hope, will be your desired sign board.